# kubectl plugin tab auto complete not working with zsh

Tags: kubectl, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

After installing kubernetes-cli via homebrew in a mac with zsh, the kubernetes auto complete is not working completely or in full. Only the first tab works and not the second tab onwards. Example, if I type `kubectl [TAB]`, it displays the sub commands for `kubectl`, and now if I select a sub command and press [TAB], eg `kubectl get [TAB]`, it freezes for a lot of time and nothing happens there after.

I tried the following ways

1. Installed kubectl-cli via home brew
2. enabled zsh plugin
3. added the below code as well

   ```
   source <(kubectl completion zsh)
   autoload -Uz compinit
   compinit
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Finally this worked after referring to https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#zsh**

```
echo '[[ $commands[kubectl] ]] && source <(kubectl completion zsh)' >> ~/.zshrc # add autocomplete permanently to your zsh shell
```

**The below did not work**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-zsh/

Comment: I had the same problem: the autocomplete just stopped working one day. It fixed it, thank you :)